# java casting confusion

Tags: java, casting

Could anyone please tell me why the following casting is resulting in compile time error:

```
Long l = (Long)Math.pow(5,2);
```

But why not the following:

```
long l = (long)Math.pow(5,2);
```

Comment: It would be good if you include the compiler error, just for better understanding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Math.pow(5,2)` is a `double`, which can be cast to `long`. It can not be cast to `Long`.

This would however work fine, thanks to [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) which converts between `long` and `Long`:

```
Long l = (long)Math.pow(5,2);
```

To summarize, you can convert `double --> long`  and `long --> Long`, but not `double --> Long`

Comment: Math.pow(a,b) is a double. Autoboxing does the trick as you mention.

Comment: @Martin - Just a random type of question (+1 to answer, BTW) - would this work in C# since primitives derive from objects?

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast a primitive type (like `double`) directly to an object. That's just not how Java works. There are some situations where the language can apply the appropriate object creation for you, like function call arguments.

Comment: The browser?  You mean the Java Runtime Engine?

Comment: you can cast primitive double directly to object Double.

Comment: oops thanks @Monkey!  Also yes there's boxing/unboxing now, but it's marginally evil and I prefer to keep my head in the sand :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because primitive types are not object at all effects also if java added some workarounds (like *implicit unboxing* of these types).

You can sole it in various ways, like:

```
Long l3 = ((Double)Math.pow(5, 2)).longValue();
```

This works because Java is able:

- to implicit cast from a primitive type to another one when you refer to them just with normal type declaration eg: `int` to `long`
- to implicit cast from a boxed type to another one eg. `Int` to `Long`
- to switch between boxed and unboxed type when they are the same type eg `long` to `Long`